Catpture output of Linux command `needrestart`
I'm trying to capture the output of Linux command needrestart, but I'm having no luck...
After intensive googling, I would expect the following to work:
root@NASLG2:/home/erik# needrestart 2> /home/erik/needrestartoutput.txt

But /home/erik/needrestartoutput.txt remains empty...
Any thoughts?
(My goal is to check whether the output of needrestart contains the substring Service restarts being deferred:.)
Edit:
The following also has no effect on needrerstartoutput.txt:
root@NASLG2:/home/erik# needrestart > /home/erik/needrestartoutput.txt

Solution:
needrestart -v > /home/erik/needrestartoutput.txt

Some more insight:
I was actually on my way to create this:
#!/bin/bash
NEEDRESTART=$(needrestart -v)
STRINGTOSEARCH="Service restarts being deferred"

if [[ "$NEEDRESTART" =~ "$STRINGTOSEARCH" ]]
then
        reboot
fi

The above question rose because I wanted to see the output in a file, since I was unable to get it as a variable. But the file itself I do not need.

You're writing the error output to the file, not the standard output. Is that what you want? stdout is written with just > rather than 2>.

Same (non) result...

Are you seeing the output on the terminal instead of the file?

If you're not seeing the output on the terminal or the file, then it's just not printing anything. Try using -v for verbose output.

needrestart -v > /home/erik/needrestartoutput.txt did the trick!

Some programs generate different default output depending on whether they're writing to a terminal or file/pipe. Seems like needrestart is like that.

How can I mark this question as resolved...?

Apparently needrestart doesn't produce output by default when its output is redirected. Add the -v option for verbose output.
needrestart -v > filename

